# How do I perform multiple left joins while maintaining an existing index?

Tags: indexing, sas, proc-sql

In SAS, I have a large table that I want to increment with information from multiple small tables by performing left joins (or equivalent). My logic requires many steps (i.e. can't join everything at the same time). After each join, I want to keep large_table's existing index, making the best use of it. How can I rewrite the following code to accomplish this?

```
/*Join 1*/
proc sql;
  create table large_table as
  select a.*, b.newinfo1
  from large_table a
  left join small_table1 b on a.id = b.id;
quit;

/*some logic*/

/*Join 2*/
proc sql;
  create table large_table as
  select a.*, b.newinfo2
  from large_table a
  left join small_table2 b on a.id = b.id;
quit;

/*...*/
```

Comment: Why can't you join everything in a single query?  That is what SQL does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because my logic is very complex. I have multiple data sources that I need to preprocess, and much of that processing requires information from previous joins.

Comment: So then create subqueries to preprocess whatever data you need and then select from those subqueries.  You should still be doing the whole thing in a single query

Comment: @DanielMarcus I seriously can't do everything in a single query. I already stated that in the question because I knew some people would suggest that. I have a complex data pipeline that has to be executed in multiple steps, with conditional branches, and at different times. Maybe I'll run some of it this week, and another part next week. However, I still want to use an index to speed things up without needing to rebuild it (since most of what I'm doing are left joins).

Comment: Have you tried, simply recreating the index on `large_table` after you created it?  Indexes usually don't take long to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better would certainly be to perform one query.  But if you don't have that ability, you have a few options.

The most SAS-like is not a SQL query but a `MODIFY` statement.  This performs a left join, and modifies the master dataset - doesn't replace it.  You do have to have all of the variables pre-defined for this to work.

```
data class(index=(name));
  set sashelp.class;
  call missing(predict);  *define PREDICT so it is available to be updated;
  where sex='F';
run;

data classfit(index=(name));
  set sashelp.classfit;
run;

data class;
  modify class classfit;  *only PREDICT will be appended here;
  by name;
  select (_IORC_);  *this processes the 'left' join;
    when (%sysrc(_sok))  replace;   *if in master then replace;
    when (%sysrc(_dsenmr)) delete;  *if not in master then delete;
    otherwise abort;
  end;
run;

proc contents data=class;
run;
```

You could do something similar in SQL using an `UPDATE` statement.

```
proc sql;
  update class
    set predict = (
      select predict from classfit
      where class.name=classfit.name
      );
quit;

proc contents data=class;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

A left join equivalent for single new column is a SAS custom format.  Create two new custom formats from the small table and instead of rebuilding the large table, create a view that repeats the id twice, applying the new formats to the repeats -- extending the view scope of the information.

A solution centered on a view makes the large_table extension responsive to any changes in the small tables when the small table concept formats are updated.

For example

```
data fmt1 / view=fmt1;
  fmtname = 'small_1_concept';
  set small_table1(rename=(id=start newinfo1=label));
run;
data fmt2 / view=fmt2;
  fmtname = 'small_2_concept';
  set small_table2(rename=(id=start newinfo2=label));
run;

proc format cntlin=fmt1;
proc format cntlin=fmt2;

proc sql;
  create view large_table_extended_v as
  select 
    large_table.*
  , id as id1 format=small_1_concept.
  , id as id2 format=small_2_concept.
  from
    large_table
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Note that a view might, or might not, be a good solution, depending on what you're doing ultimately and how often you're going to have to run it.  But a format could be used in a MODIFY data step, or an UPDATE sql query, just as easily.

Comment: To add new columns to an existing table containing indices, you would need to ALTER TABLE via SQL or DATASETS first, which might in turn cause the base table to be rewritten.  Once the new columns are in place, sure MODIFY statement or UPDATE clause can *replicate* small data information into the large table.  Original question does not provide enough large/small information to determine if replication of *newinfo* values would cause other problems.